# Unable to install package googleVis with R 3.0.1

Tags: r, installation, googlevis

I need to install googleVis. I am using R version 3.0.1.

However on trying to install the package I get the below error :

```
> install.packages("googleVis")
Installing package into ‘/home/akash/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning message:
package ‘googleVis’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1) 
>
```

I get the same error from Rstudio also.

R version info :

```
akash@akash:~$ R

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Kindly Help.

Comment: You could upgrade your R version to the current (`R 3.1.2`) and try.

Comment: Please check this link,  You have the change the version http://askubuntu.com/questions/431380/how-to-install-upgrade-r-base-to-3-02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @akrun said, you need to update your r version to `3.1.2`. It seems like you're on Ubuntu, if yes, then you could run the below commands on terminal to update your  `r` package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Then try to install `googleVis` r package by running `install.packages("googleVis")` command on r prompt.

Comment: Hi. Thanks fro reply. On typing the commands I get "sudo apt-get install r-base".  The version is still 3.0.1 though.

Comment: did you run `sudo apt-get update`  command before installing the `r-base` package?

Comment: post the output of `apt-cache policy r-base` command on your question.

Comment: I did run the update command.The ouptut of apt-cache command is :          `code`r-base:
  Installed: 3.0.1-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.0.1-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.1-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status `code`

Comment: @art follow this http://askubuntu.com/a/431410/202806 answer. in the second command `deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu precise`, replace precise with the name of your ubuntu version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67293/discussion-between-artemis-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. So I updated to the latest R version R 4.3.3 (windows), then changed my browser default settings to Chrome. It worked, though the output was on the browser.